# How to calculate percentage of accuracy of game-play based on the number of mistakes, blunders and inaccuracies?

Tags: engines, analysis, online-chess

For some time now, [chess.com analysis](https://www.chess.com/analysis/game/live/4732283873) suggests the accuracy of the gameplay based on the blunders, mistakes and inaccuracies, one committed during his/her gameplay. Now, my question is,

**Whether there is any formula to calculate the accuracy of gameplay based on the inaccuracies, blunders and mistakes during the game? If not, then what are the other factors, that act on the accuracy?**

Comment: You can do it pretty much however you want. How does chess.com calculate it is another question, though

Answer (score 5):

The gameplay accuracy is a scale from 0 to 100 and it is calculated based on the accuracy of each of your moves. Chess.com collects a lot of data from played games that they use to evaluate which moves are more important for the final accuracy.

The final accuracy is a [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) and that explains when you play a [game with two book moves and a blunder](https://www.chess.com/analysis/game/live/5177034436) why you can get an accuracy of 0.7 and not 66.7.

The average of a single move is determined by how close the evaluation deviates from the top engine suggestion and how far is the evaluation rank placed. If the move played was the 2nd best but was -3 instead of best -1, then that is more accurate than if the same move had 9th rank.

Chess.com has released these two articles that give some insight on the analysis:
[How is it measured?](https://support.chess.com/article/1135-what-is-accuracy-in-analysis-how-is-it-measured#:%7E:text=At%20the%20end%20of%20a,for%20your%20accuracy%20that%20game.&text=90%25%20of%20the%20time%2C%20overall,to%20chess%20than%20just%20Accuracy!)
[How to use game analysis?](https://support.chess.com/article/365-how-do-i-use-game-analysis)

**Note:**
Chess.com isn't open source and they haven't shared all the details of the calculation, so more explanation needs more speculation.

Answer (score -2):

You cant.  They are just a rough guide about how you did.

The only factor is who won/lost the game.